# Showing loader.gif with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I want to use a loader gif while retrieving data through AJAX with getJSON. I have not found proper solution yet. I have used this  `$("#loader").show();` and this `$("#loader").hide();` but its starts as soon as page loads. I want it to work when i click the search button.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Here is the my html codes:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <section id="gallery">
                <input type="text" id="KUNDE"  placeholder="Search by name or ID." /> <di id="loader"><img src="loader.gif"/></di>
                <button id="buton" type="button" class="btn-style" value="search" onclick="find();">Search</button>
                <button id="button" class="btn-style">Clean Results</button>

            </section>
            <ul id="list"><li> </li> </ul>
        </div>
```

Here is the my jquery codes:

```
<script>          
            $("#button").click(function (e) {
                $("#list").find('li').remove();
            });
            $(function () {
                $("#KUNDE").focus();
            });
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $("#buton").click();
                }
            });
            var uri = 'navisioncustomer.json';
            function find() {
                var info = $('#KUNDE').val();
                $("#loader").show();
                $.getJSON(uri)                
                    .done(function (data) {
                        var item = data.filter(function (obj) {
                            return obj.name === info || obj.ID === info;
                        })[0];
                        if (typeof item !== 'undefined' || item !== null) {
                            $("#list").append("<li>ID      = " + item.ID + "<br />Name    = " + item.name + "<br />Phone      = " + item.phone + "<br />Contact       = " + item.contact + "<br />BalanceLCY      = " + item.balanceLCY + "<br /> CreditLimitLCY       = " + item.creditLimitLCY + "</li>");
                        }
                    })               
                           .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                               $('#KUNDE').text('Error: ' + err);
                           });
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
            var options = {
                url: "navisioncustomer.json",
                getValue: "name",
                list: {
                    match: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                theme: "square"
            };
            $("#KUNDE").easyAutocomplete(options);                       
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.always` callback of JSON, read more on: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
function find() {
    var info = $('#KUNDE').val();
    $("#loader").show();
    $.getJSON(uri)                
        .done(function (data) {
            var item = data.filter(function (obj) {
                return obj.name === info || obj.ID === info;
            })[0];
            if (typeof item !== 'undefined' || item !== null) {
                $("#list").append("<li>ID      = " + item.ID + "<br />Name    = " + item.name + "<br />Phone      = " + item.phone + "<br />Contact       = " + item.contact + "<br />BalanceLCY      = " + item.balanceLCY + "<br /> CreditLimitLCY       = " + item.creditLimitLCY + "</li>");
            }
        })               
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#KUNDE').text('Error: ' + err);
        })
        .always(function () { $("#loader").hide(); });
}
```

What your original code is saying `show the loader > make request > hide the loader`, and using callback to hide the loader will wait till the result

Comment: Now loader.gif disappeared as soon as I print the json data. Do you have any succession as well how can i fire it when I click the search button, because its starts showing loader.gif  as soon as page is load.  Thank you.

Comment: I think the above code will call `$("#loader").show()` when you call the `find()` since it is wrapped inside the `function find()`. So if it is displaying as soon as page load, there should be somewhere else fired the `.show()` or `find()` on page load, or you didn't hide the `#loader` on it's initial state. Try add `#loader { display: none; }` to your CSS to see what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can set the loader div to be hidden by default when the page loads.

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="loader.gif"/></div>
```

Your code in jQuery can then handle the `$("#loader").hide()` and `$("#loader").show()` as required based on the events.

Additionally in your jsp code it looks like its `<di>` and not `<div>`

Comment: Thank you very much. This was also very useful for me.